# JavaScript Bracket RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace this: "[ID]" with this "ad231-3213-e12211"

I was using this regular expression: `/\[ID\]/i`

And it was working perfectly with `.replace(/\[ID\]/i, id)`

Now I encapsulated it in this function:

```
self.changeUrl = function (url, id, replaceExp) {
    replaceExp = replaceExp === 'undefined' ? new RegExp("\[ID\]") : replaceExp instanceof RegExp ? replaceExp : new RegExp("\[ID\]"); // basically ensure that this is a regexp

    return url.replace(replaceExp, id);
};
```

and this:

```
self.changeUrl = function (url, id, replaceExp) {
    replaceExp = replaceExp === 'undefined' ? new RegExp("\u005BID\u005D") : replaceExp instanceof RegExp ? replaceExp : new RegExp("\u005BID\u005D"); // basically ensure that this is a regexp

    return url.replace(replaceExp, id);
};
```

And neither of them work, what is it that I am missing?

Comment: Thanks, post is an answer and why you have to do that and i will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are passing a string to your `RegExp` constructor, you'd need to escape the `\` character inside the string as well. Therefore, use `\\[` which will actually become `\[` inside the string variable; whereas `\[` will become `[` only.

```
new RegExp( "\\[ID\\]" )
```

Answer (score 2):

To be sure:

If you want to replace a fixed substring like `[ID]` you do not need regex at all, you can simply write:

```
self.changeUrl = function (url, id, replaceExp) {
   return (replaceExp instanceof RegExp) ? url.replace(replaceExp, id)
                                         : url.replace('[ID]', id);
};
```

or

```
self.changeUrl = function (url, id, replaceExp) {
   return (replaceExp === 'undefined') ? url.replace('[ID]', id)
                                       : url.replace(replaceExp, id);
};
```

*(depending of the behaviour you want to have)*

Comment: That is a very interesting answer, the only thing that I would say is that using regex opens more options for replacing. If `[ID]` where not good enough, then it might have to be made more complex etc.

Comment: @No1_Melman: The two functions can be called with a RegExp instance as third parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`"\[ID\]"` - this basically translates in regex as `[ID]` because a backslash in JavaScript is used as an escape character